# Problemas en el proceso de pago

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo una web WordPress (con WooCommerce y Elementor) y al finalizar el carrito se laguea la tabla de checkout, queda eternamente cargando así:

[image: ver screenshot acá]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuál puede ser el problema?

Actualización: probé con cambiar de theme pero sigue fallando (actualmente estoy usando Martfury)

Comment: Devuelve un error 500, el server no logra procesar el checkout, prueba a aumentar la memoria RAM o ir desactivando plugins, puede que alguno te cause el problema, este es uno de los problemas más comunes cuando se utilizan muchos complementos, sitios pesados con muchas inconsistencias.

Comment: Muchas gracias!